# css - content scrolls to top when the curser moves in IE (leafletjs)

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and have add the height and overflow items to this css;

```
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
color: #333;
background: #fff;
max-height: 500px;
height: auto !important;
overflow:auto;
}
```

now, whenever I move the curser in this div, it scrolls up to the top, and I can't get to the content below.  This only happens in IE & works fine others.  I need the overflow in, as the div contains a long list, which goes off the bottom of the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a fiddle with your JS included, 

I think that you havn't set your controller position on init, but i can't tell from this example. Also, don't use !important, it means that something's usually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This may be delayed, but it is due to the leaflet using the mouseover and mouseout events. Mouseout events are also triggered by the child nodes, so essentially each time the dropdown is hovered over or scrolled, a mouseout event is triggered which IE doesn't appreciate. This results in the rapid opening/closing of the layer control and the resetting of the scroll bar seen in IE. A fix has been added to the upcoming release of Leaflet (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2544) but in the meantime, you can simply modify the layout control portion of the code for the collapsing and expansion of the control to use mouseenter and mouseout, instead.

Old:

```
if (!L.Browser.android) {
            L.DomEvent
                .on(container, 'mouseover', this._expand, this)
                .on(container, 'mouseout', this._collapse, this);
        }
```

New:

```
if (!L.Browser.android) {
            L.DomEvent
                .on(container, 'mouseenter', this._expand, this)
                .on(container, 'mouseleave', this._collapse, this);
        }
```